# Segfault when changing macro values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define len 10
#define hi 10

void transpose(double (*matrix)[len][hi]);

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  double (*matrix)[len][hi] = (double (*)[len][hi])malloc(sizeof(double[len][hi]));
  double delimo, delitel;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < hi; j++){
      delimo = rand()%(len * hi);
      delitel = rand()%(len * hi);
      *matrix[i][j] = delimo/++delitel;
      printf(" %5.2lf ", *matrix[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
  puts("Transpose: ");
    transpose(matrix);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < hi; j++){
        printf(" %5.2lf ", *matrix[i][j]);
      }
      puts("");
    }
   free(matrix);

}

void transpose(double (*matrix)[len][hi]){
  double (*Tmatrix)[len][hi] = (double (*)[len][hi])malloc(sizeof(double[len][hi]));
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < hi; j++){
      *Tmatrix[i][j] = *matrix[j][i];
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < hi; j++){
      *matrix[i][j] = *Tmatrix[i][j];
    }
  }
  free(Tmatrix);
}
```

Task is to allocate a 2d array and then have a function transpose it and copy the transposed matrix in the original one with one function call. The dimensions of the matrix are set by the macros and they are also used in a few loops and when allocating the 2 matrixes. Yet for some odd reason, there's a segfault if I decide to change them. Only thing that has never crashed is when `len = hi = 10` . In any other case the program has an average to above average chance to crash.

Comment: you are using `iostream` in `c`?

Comment: @Observer Yes, for reading data from `stdin` as `cin` and `cin.ignore()` often works better than almost everything `C` has to offer.

Comment: What are the changed values that crash?  What line does it crash on? Your question is missing information. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: I think that [This is what you need](https://ideone.com/qupbMI)

Comment: @user694733 I mentioned it already,anything different from 10 has a chance of crashing, regardless if `len` is equal to `hi` or not. 
Debugger: 
"Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.                                                                                  
0x00007ffff7a4af79 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)                                                                         
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56                                                                          
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory."

Comment: You can't transpose a non-square matrix in situ, can you?  If `hi != len`, you need a different shape of matrix for the transpose.  Also, don't you need `(*matrix)[i][j]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown in the question gives my build of [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) conniptions because it is not using the pointer-to-matrix notation correctly.  When run standalone (not under Valgrind) it appears to work, but the output matrix is not a transpose of the input matrix — because the data has not been accessed correctly.  This is an example of the bogus output I get. You can see that the elements with indices 0,1 and 1,0 in the 'transpose' matrix are unrelated to the elements in the original matrix.

```
  1.24   2.64   0.17   0.49  22.25   4.30   0.71   1.12   1.03   2.31 
  1.39   7.18   0.40   0.44   4.30   0.17   0.62  12.67   0.34   9.10 
  2.85   0.69   3.50   1.58   0.77   0.04   0.26   0.79   0.24   1.59 
 16.00   0.14   0.12   0.56   1.68   0.08   0.69   0.13   2.51   1.74 
  5.50   0.96   0.45   1.00   0.00   0.84   0.97   0.40   2.14   0.67 
  2.00   0.14   1.84   0.88   1.26   0.21   0.70   0.30   1.74   0.60 
  2.04   1.00   0.35   0.12   0.00   0.65   1.21   0.18   0.52   9.70 
  1.19   1.08   0.88   1.71   0.88   0.21   1.74   0.70   0.44   1.23 
  1.38   0.69   0.12   0.14   4.18   3.17   0.06   7.10   8.00   1.52 
  0.16   6.07   0.81   0.49   0.14   1.37   4.00   0.93   0.98   1.48 
Transpose: 
  1.24   1.24   2.64   0.17   0.49  22.25   4.30   0.71   1.12   1.03 
 -2.00   1.39   1.39   2.85  16.00   5.50   2.00   2.04   1.19   1.38 
  0.17   2.85   0.69   0.69   0.14   0.96   0.14   1.00   1.08   0.69 
  0.49  16.00   0.14   0.12   0.12   0.45   1.84   0.35   0.88   0.12 
 22.25   5.50   0.96   0.45   1.00   1.00   0.88   0.12   1.71   0.14 
  4.30   2.00   0.14   1.84   0.88   1.26   1.26   0.00   0.88   4.18 
  0.71   2.04   1.00   0.35   0.12   0.00   0.65   0.65   0.21   3.17 
  1.12   1.19   1.08   0.88   1.71   0.88   0.21   1.74   1.74   0.06 
  1.03   1.38   0.69   0.12   0.14   4.18   3.17   0.06   7.10   7.10 
  2.31   0.16   6.07   0.81   0.49   0.14   1.37   4.00   0.93   0.98
```

The code below works for square matrices.  The difference is that the pointer-to-matrix is dereferenced before the subscripting is applied (`(*matrix)[i][j]`) instead of after (`*matrix[i][j]`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define len 10
#define hi 10

void transpose(double (*matrix)[len][hi]);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double (*matrix)[len][hi] = (double (*)[len][hi])malloc(sizeof(double[len][hi]));
    double delimo, delitel;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++)
        {
            delimo = rand() % (len * hi);
            delitel = rand() % (len * hi);
            (*matrix)[i][j] = delimo / ++delitel;
            printf(" %5.2lf ", (*matrix)[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("Transpose: ");
    transpose(matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++)
        {
            printf(" %5.2lf ", (*matrix)[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    free(matrix);
}

void transpose(double (*matrix)[len][hi])
{
    double (*Tmatrix)[len][hi] = (double (*)[len][hi])malloc(sizeof(double[len][hi]));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++)
        {
            (*Tmatrix)[i][j] = (*matrix)[j][i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++)
        {
            (*matrix)[i][j] = (*Tmatrix)[i][j];
        }
    }
    free(Tmatrix);
}
```

Example output:

```
  0.98   0.90   0.16   0.08   0.48   1.71   0.53   0.24   2.28   1.79 
  0.73   0.36   2.00   3.27   0.29   1.25  19.40   1.60   0.56   0.00 
  3.00  10.50   1.81   1.56   1.11   0.78   1.53   0.71   1.27   0.93 
  2.10   0.56   2.34   1.48   0.81   2.16   0.47   0.16   7.62   0.91 
  0.93   2.48   0.15   0.71   1.09   0.73   0.58   0.48   1.13   0.99 
  0.59   0.72   8.75   2.19  61.00   1.41   2.08   0.83   0.65   0.16 
  0.42   1.13   0.85   1.00   3.00   0.55   0.33   1.67   0.44   0.69 
  0.08   1.17   0.25   0.92   1.04   0.17   1.77   1.95   0.50   0.90 
  2.28   0.35   0.41   1.27   0.80   3.36   0.29   0.13   3.88   0.39 
  0.64   0.50   0.40   0.15   0.45   0.78   0.31   1.48   1.50   1.06 
Transpose: 
  0.98   0.73   3.00   2.10   0.93   0.59   0.42   0.08   2.28   0.64 
  0.90   0.36  10.50   0.56   2.48   0.72   1.13   1.17   0.35   0.50 
  0.16   2.00   1.81   2.34   0.15   8.75   0.85   0.25   0.41   0.40 
  0.08   3.27   1.56   1.48   0.71   2.19   1.00   0.92   1.27   0.15 
  0.48   0.29   1.11   0.81   1.09  61.00   3.00   1.04   0.80   0.45 
  1.71   1.25   0.78   2.16   0.73   1.41   0.55   0.17   3.36   0.78 
  0.53  19.40   1.53   0.47   0.58   2.08   0.33   1.77   0.29   0.31 
  0.24   1.60   0.71   0.16   0.48   0.83   1.67   1.95   0.13   1.48 
  2.28   0.56   1.27   7.62   1.13   0.65   0.44   0.50   3.88   1.50 
  1.79   0.00   0.93   0.91   0.99   0.16   0.69   0.90   0.39   1.06
```

You can't transpose a non-square matrix in situ.  If you have an `n`x`m` matrix as input, the transpose is an `m`x`n` matrix.  It is probably simplest to allocate the transpose matrix where you allocate the non-transpose, and pass both matrices to the transpose function.  Note the use of `*matrix` to pass the pointer-to-matrix as a matrix to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void transpose(int rows, int cols, double matrix[rows][cols], double result[cols][rows]);
void print_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, double matrix[rows][cols]);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int cols = 10;
    int rows =  8;
    double (*matrix)[rows][cols] = malloc(sizeof(double[rows][cols]));
    double (*result)[cols][rows] = malloc(sizeof(double[cols][rows]));
    if (matrix == 0 || result == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            double delimo = rand() % (rows * cols);
            double delitel = rand() % (rows * cols) + 1;
            (*matrix)[i][j] = delimo / delitel;
        }
    }

    print_matrix("original", rows, cols, *matrix);
    transpose(rows, cols, *matrix, *result);
    print_matrix("transpose", cols, rows, *result);

    free(matrix);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}

void print_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, double matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf(" %5.2f ", matrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void transpose(int rows, int cols, double matrix[rows][cols], double result[cols][rows])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
original (8x10):
  0.84   0.92   0.18   1.97   4.54  31.00   1.59   0.11   0.35   0.07 
  0.96   3.19   1.00   4.86   3.25   3.50   2.65   1.07   0.24   0.77 
  6.00   0.13   0.40   1.04   0.99   0.88   1.24   0.67   3.07  12.00 
  1.89   0.48   0.72   0.55   0.26   0.64   0.55   0.09   0.30   0.98 
  0.51   0.86   0.85   0.33   1.44   0.89   2.38   2.21   0.27   2.12 
  6.40   1.71   2.83   1.61   0.76   0.13   0.81   1.48   1.13   0.51 
  0.79   0.69   0.57   1.10   1.00   1.31   0.68   1.95   1.42   0.46 
  0.00   0.43   1.64   0.88   1.03   0.14   0.35   1.78   0.86   2.82 
transpose (10x8):
  0.84   0.96   6.00   1.89   0.51   6.40   0.79   0.00 
  0.92   3.19   0.13   0.48   0.86   1.71   0.69   0.43 
  0.18   1.00   0.40   0.72   0.85   2.83   0.57   1.64 
  1.97   4.86   1.04   0.55   0.33   1.61   1.10   0.88 
  4.54   3.25   0.99   0.26   1.44   0.76   1.00   1.03 
 31.00   3.50   0.88   0.64   0.89   0.13   1.31   0.14 
  1.59   2.65   1.24   0.55   2.38   0.81   0.68   0.35 
  0.11   1.07   0.67   0.09   2.21   1.48   1.95   1.78 
  0.35   0.24   3.07   0.30   0.27   1.13   1.42   0.86 
  0.07   0.77  12.00   0.98   2.12   0.51   0.46   2.82
```

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) gives both of these a clean bill of health.  The original code caused Valgrind to report a lot of errors like:

```
==33404== Signal 11 being dropped from thread 0's queue
```

I had to kill that run from a different terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to transpose a matrix *in place*, which is problematic. Indeed, transposing a non-square matrix gives a matrix of different dimension. Therefore you will inadvertently write to memory you are not supposed to access, because you try to fit your transposed matrix in an array of incorrect dimension.

I suggest you to modify your transpose function such that it takes two matrices as arguments. The first is your matrix to transpose, the second is the one receiving the transposed matrix and it has the correct dimension.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying too hard. Simply remove all the dynamic allocation stuff as well as pointers. Dynamic memory allocation is totally useless in your case.

Here you go:

```
#define len 2
#define hi 2

void transpose(double matrix[len][hi]);

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  double matrix[len][hi];
  double delimo, delitel;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
      delimo = rand() % (len * hi);
      delitel = rand() % (len * hi);
      matrix[i][j] = delimo / ++delitel;
      printf(" %5.2lf ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
  puts("Transpose: ");
  transpose(matrix);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
      printf(" %5.2lf ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}

void transpose (double matrix[len][hi]) {
  double Tmatrix[len][hi];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
      Tmatrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = Tmatrix[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer:

- this only works for square matrixes.
- there may be other problems

Comment: I didn't down-vote but this should be written with 21th century C instead: `void transpose(size_t len, size_t hi, double matrix[len][hi]);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I didn't downvote it either, my question got downvoted for no reason as well. And because of this I can't ask other questions for the next few days. This is retarded, questions like this one are "bad" but questions that can be solved easily by reading documentation are upvoted like hell.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I disagree with your statement that memory allocation is _totaly_ useless here. It can work without memory allocation but if OP now wants a matrix of dimension 1000x1000 (which is still reasonable), he will provoke a stack-overflow quite easily. Simply because these matrices have automatic storage duration (they are declared local and non-static) therefore they are allocated on the stack which is limited in size.

Comment: @OlegPlachkov you are totally right. Ridiculous here. +1 from me. I hope it helps you.